# Initial curve in Level-Set-Method

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am learning Level-Set-Method for the image segmentation.

I have a simple question, how people draw the initial closed curve in the given image, when people need  to deform the closed curve?

Is there a code in MATLAB, or we need create it by ourselves?

Comment: Often its created by making either a curve as big as the image (if you shrink the level set) or a curve inside a pixel (for level sets growing the curve)

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the result of Level Sets, I'll typically use [`contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) and specify that I only want the 0 contour (the 0 level set). This will automatically deal with multiple contours etc.

```
% Just generate a generic level set function (phi)
[~, ~, phi] = peaks;

% Create contours using the zero level set
contour(phi, [0 0])
```